# How to build your own preset(node) in Animation Nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

How to build your own preset(node) like spider generetor or procedural wire generator?

Comment: Have you looked at [the docs](http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev_guide/node_development/index.html)?

Comment: No, I have not seen this. Thank you. But in this documentation about coding. Is it possible to do something like a grouping. As in the nodes of the material?